Why in linear proportional relationships do they incorporate a $(0,0)$ when $x=0$ and $y=0$ do not have a ratio?
When you do $y=2x$ you get this
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
x & y \\
\hline
-3 & -6 \\
-2 & -4 \\
-1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 \\
2 & 4 \\
3 & 6 \\
\end{array}$$
All of these have a common ration of $2$ as $6/3 = 2$ and $4/2 = 2$ and $-2/-1 = 2$, but $0/0$ is undefined! So why do proportional graphs have $(0,0)$?

The other points fit $y=2x$, the point $(0,0)$ fits all proportional relationships.

If $y$ is proportional to $x$, then there is some constant $k$ such that
$$
y = kx \text{ for every value of } x
$$
No matter what that constant $k$ is, $x=y=0$ always satisfies that relation.
It is true that $\frac y x = k$ is another way to frame proportionality (i.e. a constant ratio), but that assumes that $x \ne 0$ and hence is a bit stricter.

ah so we must say that y/x but x!=0. If so then I understand
